# System.SysUtils.FileExists doesn't work in network folder

Tags: delphi

The function below is simple, it just returns if the file exists or not.

```
function TWStartConfig._FileExists(sFileDir: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := System.SysUtils.FileExists(sFileDir);
end;
```

When `sFileDir := 'd:\test.txt'`, it works.

When `sFileDir := '\\10.0.0.71\public\test.txt'`, it doesn't work. I have access by Windows Explorer.

I've tried `System.IOUtils.TFile.Exists()` but I'm getting the same return.

Comment: Are you running your executable under the same account as your account that has access by Windows Explorer?

Comment: yes, the program is running by the same user

Comment: `FileExists()` uses `FindFirstFile()` - try that one. See also [Why do FindFirstFile / FindNextFile sometimes see a file on a network folder, but CopyFile does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29798193/4299358)

Comment: Thank's for the tip @AmigoJack
I've created a new function based on FindFirstFile

Answer (score 0):

I changed my function using `System.SysUtils.FindFirstFile` insted of `System.SysUtils.FileExists`.
It's important to consider that the program runs on Windows.

```
function TWStartConfig._FileExists(sFileDir: string): Boolean;
    var
        wfd: WIN32_FIND_DATA;
        handle: THandle;
    begin
        handle := FindFirstFile(PChar(sFileDir), wfd);
        Result := handle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    end;
```

Comment: This does nowhere answer if it solves your problem. Also it will return `TRUE` for folders (contrary to its name).

Comment: And you need to close the handle when you've got one.